# Is it possible to use Cocoa UI elements in Adobe Air for iOS?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I think the question is quite clear. I'd like to use native UI elements in some part of my Air for iOS app.

Is that possible?

Is there some UI library that mimics iOS buttons and such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the best shot so far.

http://code.google.com/p/flexpad/

If I find better options I will be updating this answer.